# Compare two strings with version numbers in them

Tags: c#, sql, .net, string

I need to compare 2 strings in SQL that are in the following format:

> name_1.2.3

Can someone explain how to compare them correctly? How do you compare non-int value?

I had an issue in the past when you compare strings with numbers: the comparison is done literally. This gets me into problems like where "`name_1.5.3`" is "bigger" than "`name_1.20.3`", because it probably compares char by char, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Some SQL or C# example will be really helpful.

Part of my code in C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PDCs.Count(); i++)
{ 
    if (foundInstallOrder)
    {
        string justNumbers = new String(PDCs[i].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        a = Convert.ToInt32(justNumbers);
        if (projPDCs.Count() <= i)
        {
            b = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            justNumbers = new String(projPDCs[i].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(justNumbers);
        }

        if (a > b )//compare the currentPDC with the projfound, if result is 1 => that means current is within range
        {
            foundInstallOrder = true;
            arrayInstallOrder.Add(lines);
            break;
        }

        else if (a == b)  //numbers are equal
        {
            foundInstallOrder = true;
        }
        else                                 //lower
        {
            foundInstallOrder = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is too complex, it is working but I'm trying to find a better solution.

Comment: You should probably parse the strings first, and write a comparer for the resulting data structures.

Comment: What do those numbers mean? If they're so important, put each of them in a separate column during insert.

Comment: Use a numeric sensitive collation when comparing the values. create collation numeric from eor using '[Numeric On]'; (If your DBMS supports create collation...)

Comment: I do not know if this exactly helps you but you might want to look for an alphanumerical-sort-algorithm or an alphanumerical-comparator. Also the IComparer interface might be of importance to find the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do suggest that you keep those numbers in a separate column in the table for easier/faster querying, you can also solve this by adding regular expression support to SQL server and use it in your query.

**SETUP**

Create a .NET Class Library, named 'SqlExtensions', containing this code:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace SqlExtensions
{
    public static partial class UserDefinedFunctions
    {
        [SqlFunction]
        public static SqlString RegexGroup(SqlString input, SqlString pattern, SqlString name)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern.Value, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            Match match = regex.Match(input.Value);
            return match.Success ? new SqlString(match.Groups[name.Value].Value) : SqlString.Null;
        }
    }
}
```

Build in Release.

Then, add the class library to SQL server using SQL Server Management Studio:

- Connect to database server
- Expand `Databases`
- Expand the database you're working on
- Expand `Programmability`
- Right-click `Assemblies`
- Add new assembly by browsing to the Class Library DLL created above

Add the Scalar-valued function to the database using SQL Server Management Studio:

- Select the database you're working on
- Click `New Query` and execute this query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RegexGroup] (@input nvarchar(max), @pattern nvarchar(max), @name nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [SqlExtensions].[SqlExtensions.UserDefinedFunctions].[RegexGroup];
```

If .NET execution is not enabled, execute a new query:

- Select the database you're working on
- Click `New Query` and execute this query

```
sp_configure @configname=clr_enabled, @configvalue=1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    *,
    dbo.RegexGroup(Name, '^(?<n>[^_]*)_', 'n') AS n,
    CONVERT(INT, dbo.RegexGroup(Name, '_(?<major>[0-9]+)\.', 'major')) AS Major,
    CONVERT(INT, dbo.RegexGroup(Name, '\.(?<minor>[0-9]+)\.', 'minor')) AS Minor,
    CONVERT(INT, dbo.RegexGroup(Name, '\.(?<build>[0-9]+)$', 'build')) AS Build
FROM dbo.Table_1;
```

**RESULT**

```
name_1.5.3  name    1   5   3
name_1.20.3 name    1   20  3
name_5.19.2 name    5   19  2
name_0.6.3  name    0   6   3
name_1.20.2 name    1   20  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Tokenise the string using `String.split('.')` and then `int.parse` each "part string". This allows you to check major, minor, and build as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<NameVersion> lst = new List<NameVersion>();
        lst.Add(new NameVersion("name_1.2.3"));
        lst.Add(new NameVersion("name_1.20.3"));
        lst.Sort(delegate(NameVersion x, NameVersion y) 
        {
            int i = x.a.CompareTo(y.a);
            if (i == 0)
                i = x.b.CompareTo(y.b);
            if (i == 0)
                i = x.c.CompareTo(y.c);
            return i;
        });
    }
}

public class NameVersion
{
    public string Name = "";
    public int a, b, c;
    public NameVersion(string text)
    {
        Name = text;
        string[] sa = text.Split('_');
        string[] sb = sa[1].Split('.');
        a = Convert.ToInt32(sb[0]);
        b = Convert.ToInt32(sb[1]);
        c = Convert.ToInt32(sb[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that solution, but still don't you think this is getting too complex for comparing just a normal strings with integer values in it, I thought there might be an already existing classes for that option.

Comment: Wouldn't `PadLeft` be more appropriate here? 5 should be 005, 23 should be 023, etc?

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix The OP requires that 5 is larger than 23. It compares from left as text.

Comment: @mjb Hmm... Thats not how I read it, I read it that the problem was his sorting was seeing `.5.` as being bigger than `.23.`, which he didn't want.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix Hi, you are right. I have updated the answer :)